# Angular: methods with boolean values to share with components not working

Tags: angular, typescript, service, components

I've seen several posts about this solution, but I cannot put mine working. I have two components (same level) and lots of repeated functions that I want to put in a service. This example method with boolean values, i wrote in the service, the component can acess it, but it doesnt work. Example:

Service:

```
langSwitch(fr:boolean, eng:boolean) {
    if (fr=== true && eng === false) {
      fr = false;
      eng = true;
    } else if (fr === false && eng === true) {
      fr = true;
      eng = false;
    }
  }
```

Component:

```
engActive=true;
frActive=false;

langSwitch(){
  this.local.langSwitch(this.frActive, this.engActive);
}
```

HTML

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-10 text-right">
        <h4 (click)="langSwitch
        ()">FR</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 text-left">
        <h4 (click)="langSwitch()">EN</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Another half/working example @veben

Service:

```
mathTest( a: number, b: number, c:boolean){
    let x = a * b > 0;
    if(x){
          alert('correct');
          c = true;
          return alert(a*b)
        }

  }
```

Component TS

```
a:number;
b:number;
c=false

mathTest() {
this.local.mathTest(this.a, this.b, this.c);
```

}

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="a">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="b">
  <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="mathTest()">Calculate!</button>
  <div *ngIf="c" class="alert alert-danger col-md-6 offset-md-3" role="alert">
    Hello!
  </div>
</div>
```

With this last code, the math is done, the alerts show up, but not the div based on the c value. I dont get errors, so I have to assume that my logic is wrong..

Comment: anyone, please?

Comment: Can you edit your post and add the error you have?

Comment: the thing is that I dont have errors, the booleans just don't change the state. I will edit with another attempt

Comment: @veben, just edited now

Comment: the `c` var of your `.ts` is **false** and will always remain false, even if the `mathTest` function is done

Comment: so? I don't understand your point. It has to be false otherwise a warning message will be always displyed

Comment: my issue is to change the state of c in the service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not changing the value of `c` in your component but only locally in your service. Try the code below, based on your second example:

**Service:**

```
// return true if a * b > 0
mathTest(a: number, b: number): boolean {
    return a * b > 0;
}
```

**Component:**

```
a: number = 2;
b: number = 1;
c: boolean = false;

// Controller with service injection
// ...

ngOnInit() {
    this.c = this.local.mathTest(this.a, this.b);
}
```